# How can I integrate CC Avenue Payment Gateway in Dot Net Web API with Angular JS Website

Tags: payment-gateway, ccavenue

We are replacing Payu with CCAvenyu payment gateway. in Payu we use salt, key and Url and we putted in table, but In CCAvenyu we get MerchantId, AccessCode,workingkey.

Ensure CCAvenyu with Dot Net Web API

Please guide us for this issue.

I have and option to insert these in table and call it from nothing will